# How to get generated HTML-ID-Attribute from Symfony2-Form-Elements

Tags: symfony

I want to receive Error-Messages from a Symfony2-Form via ajax (JSON). Now I get the problem to join the $form_element->getName() with my form-element ID in HTML. Is there a possibility to get this ID from the $form_element-Object?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, simply use

```
$form->get('field_name')->createView()->vars['id'];
```

In order to get view related data (like `id` and `class` options) from a form, first you have to create its view.

You can also do it the other way:

```
$formView = $form->createView(); // Creates view for every element of the form
$id = $formView->children['field_name']->var['id'];
```

Comment: I think this is correct `$id = $formView->children['field_name']->vars['id'];`